# Cant see result of mapping through data

Tags: reactjs, redux

Cant see result of mapping through data which I am getting from google distances API as a result.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import SearchComponent from './search_component';

import _ from 'lodash';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        distances: ''
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if(newProps.Distances) {
        this.setState({
                          distances: newProps.Distances
                      })
    }
}

renderDistancesList() {
    if(_.isObject(this.state.distances)){
        let d = this.state.distances;
        console.log('this.state.distances ', d);
            return (
            <div>
                <h4>Distsances:</h4>
                {
                    _.map(d, (key, value) => {
                        return <li key={key}>{key}</li>
                    })
                }
            </div>
            )
    } else {
  return (<div>Loading data...</div>)
}
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div>HelloFrom App</div>
        <SearchComponent/>
        {this.renderDistancesList()}
    </div>
    )
}
}

function mapStateToProps({ Distances }) {
    return { Distances }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use map function from es6 not from lodash or something else 
but actually what I would do

```
renderDistancesList() {
    if(_.isObject(this.state.distances)){
        let d = this.state.distances;
        console.log('this.state.distances ', d);
            return (
            <div>
                <h4>Distsances:</h4>
                {
                   this.getData(d)
                }
            </div>
            )
    } else {
  return (<div>Loading data...</div>)
}
}


  getData(d){
    return d.map((res,key)=>{
          return <li key={key}>{key}</li>
    })
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: d.map is not a function
    at App.getData (App.js:41)
    at App.renderDistancesList (App.js:31)
    at App.render (App.js:50)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:8389)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:8357)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8982)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:11814)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:11843)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)

Comment: check if d is defined

Comment: Yes it is.I just console.log the "d" in getData() function and I got an object.d  
Object
Mega_Holon_Eilat_St_36
:
"3 770 км"
Mega_Rishon_LeTsiyon_Jabotinsky_St_44
:
"3 769 км"
Mega_Tel_Aviv_Weizman_71
:
"3 761 км"
Shufersal_Holon_HaMerkava_St_9
:
"3 765 км"
Shufersal_Petach_Tikva_Derech_Yitshak_Rabin_17
:
"3 754 км"
Shufersal_Rishon_LeTsiyon_Jabotinsky_St_16
:
"3 770 км"
Tiv_Taam_Givatayim_Sirkin_St_13
:
"3 760 км"
Tiv_Taam_Rishon_LeTsiyonDerech_HaMaccabim_62
:
"3 766 км"
Tiv_Taam_Tel_Aviv_Yafo_Dizengoff_St_16
:
"3 762 км"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: {Mega_Holon_Eilat_St_36 : "3 770 км",
Mega_Rishon_LeTsiyon_Jabotinsky_St_44 : "3 769 км",
Mega_Tel_Aviv_Weizman_71 : "3 761 км",
Shufersal_Holon_HaMerkava_St_9 : "3 765 км",
Shufersal_Petach_Tikva_Derech_Yitshak_Rabin_17 : "3 754 км",
Shufersal_Rishon_LeTsiyon_Jabotinsky_St_16 : "3 770 км",
Tiv_Taam_Givatayim_Sirkin_St_13 : "3 760 км",
Tiv_Taam_Rishon_LeTsiyonDerech_HaMaccabim_62 : "3 766 км",
Tiv_Taam_Tel_Aviv_Yafo_Dizengoff_St_16 : "3 762 км"}

Comment: I see that you have and object not an array map function iterate thru arrays not objects

Comment: So Object.keys?

Comment: try to convert your object to array

Comment: you can use replace d.map() with [...d].map()

Comment: Still getting nothing

Comment: can you send me your new array please